# Commonly used metric in NLP literature to compare ranked weighted results with variable importance for top-k results

Tags: nlp, metric, ranking

I have two different search engines that **always return the same results but in different orders**. The results consist of websites along with confidence scores, which range from 100 to 10,000. The maximum number of results is capped at 99. **Assume the results of first search engine is ideal.**

For example, consider the following sixty results by two different search engines E1 and E2:

| E1 results ( site:score) | E2 results (site:score) |
| --- | --- |
| $w_1$ - 195 | $w_4$ - 199 |
| $w_2$ - 192 | $w_{24}$ - 192 |
| $w_3$ - 190 | $w_{36}$ - 189 |
| $w_4$ - 186 | $w_3$ - 166 |
| ... | ... |
| $w_{60}$ - 105 | $w_6$ - 101 |

Given this setup, I am looking for a metric commonly used in NLP literature to compare these ranked, weighted results. **The intention is to know how similar the second list wrt to the first**. The metric should meet the following criteria:

1. Suitable for lists that are finite, small, and complete, with just websites order changed.
2. **(optional)** Includes a variable or mechanism that controls the importance of the top-k results, where k can vary from 1 to n. For instance, if k=1, the metric should primarily focus on the first result, whereas if k=n, it should give equal importance to the entire list.

Note: The websites are permuted and not scores. Scores can be different in two lists, both in order and values. For example: the highest score in E1 results is for w1, which is 95 and in E2, it is 199 for w4.